# Spring Security - how I can enable Method Security annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

There is lot of similar questions at StackOverflow, but I can't find any answered :(

I have web.xml like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and trying to configure [method security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#d0e5101) with annotations. As I see it must be done by `<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`, placed at same context as other components, `spring-web.xml` at my case. So I have following `spring-web.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"
        default-autowire="byName">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cleanplates.apiserv"/>
    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

</beans>
```

and `spring-security.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                              filters="
                                usernamePasswordProcessingFilter,
                                rememberMeFilter,
                                anonymousProcessingFilter,
                                exceptionTranslationFilter,
                                filterInvocationInterceptor"/>
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousProcessingFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="key" value="********"/>
        <property name="userAttribute">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.memory.UserAttribute">
                <property name="authoritiesAsString">
                    <list>
                        <value>ROLE_ANONYMOUS</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="password" value="none"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="usernamePasswordProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/auth/password"/>
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
        <property name="key" value="*******"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="******"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
              <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" method="GET"/>
              <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="POST"/>
              <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="PUT"/>
              <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="DELETE"/>
            </sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
        </property>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
                    <property name="key" value="***"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                    <property name="saltSource">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
                            <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
                    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class=".UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The problem that after adding `<sec:global-method-security` all controllers stop working. And I have following in logs:

```
PageNotFound:noHandlerFound:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/some/page] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

Everything is working when i remove this `global-security` element. If i'm adding it into `spring-security.xml` - nothing changes. Seems that it's not used, because methods annotated with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` (or any other role) are accessible by anyone.

PS I'm using Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: What other frameworks/libraries are you using, specifically on your controllers ? What are you deploying on ?

Comment: Current example is deploying on jetty. Actually it's jetty maven plugin, and app started as `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: There is a lot of libraries used. maven says that there about 50 libs. Seems that it's too much to put there as a comment :)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the configuration files.

Comment: @ralph i've added `spring-security.xml` also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you enable `<sec:global-method-security>` spring security creates proxies for your controllers. spring-mvc can't find annotations like `@RequestMapping` on bean in this case. If you want to use security annotations on your controllers you should extract interface of controller and put mvc annotations on it.
Spring documentation contains following note about this:

> **NOTE:** When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put *all* your mapping annotations - such as `@RequestMapping` and `@SessionAttributes` - on the controller *interface* rather than on the implementation class.

Comment: Oh, so I need to make this interfaces just for this feature? so weird :( Ok, thanks, got it

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, classic spring AOP based on java proxies and CGLIB works with annotations correctly only if you have interfaces for all of you annotated beans managed by spring, in other case there is may be different situations like this then annotation configuration will not work.

Comment: You *can* do it the other way, with no interfaces or base classes. You can set `proxy-target-class="true"` to ensure that CGLIB proxying rather than interface proxying is used. What you can't do is expect interface proxying to preserve annotations such as `@RequestMapping` on an implementing class.