# Struts2 + Spring Security 2.06: Valuestack is null when attempting to use @Secured on an Action method

Tags: java, spring, struts2, spring-security, spring-annotations

Before I begin, I've to say the closest answer I've found is [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?66381-Method-security-with-struts2-make-all-request-params-in-action-NULL) but honestly I don't really understand what's going on there.

I'm using Struts2 + Spring Security 2.06 with a custom authentication provider and access decision manager to remove the need for a "ROLE_" prefix.

My applicationContext-security.xml looks like this:

```xml
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"
                class="com.test.testconsole.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userManagementService" ref="userManagementService"/>
        <custom-authentication-provider/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Customize Spring Security's access decision manager to remove need for "ROLE_" prefix-->
    <beans:bean
            id="accessDecisionManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="roleVoter"/>
                <beans:ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
            id="roleVoter"
            class="org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
            id="authenticatedVoter"
            class="org.springframework.security.vote.AuthenticatedVoter">
    </beans:bean>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
```

Relevant portion of my web.xml:

```xml
    <!--Spring Security-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<!--Has to be placed _Before_ the struts2 filter-mapping-->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I'm simply using @Secured in one of my action classes like so:

```
@Secured({"TEST_ADMIN"})
public String editAccount() {
    logger.info("Editing account for: " + email);
    //blah blah blah
}
```

With the @Secured annotation added to a method in the action, all parameters become null, in fact looks like the valuestack is null:

```
154379 [1146701440@qtp-1897259366-0] DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler  - Entering nullPropertyValue [target=[com.test.testconsole.sections.SettingsAction@da47641, com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@1cc50164], property=currentPage]        
154379 [1146701440@qtp-1897259366-0] WARN  com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack  - Caught an exception while evaluating expression 'currentPage.equals('Summary')' against value stack
    java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method equals
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1347)
        at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
        at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
        at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:217)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.getValue(OgnlValueStack.java:342)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValue(OgnlValueStack.java:331)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValueWhenExpressionIsNotNull(OgnlValueStack.java:307)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:293)
        at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:382)
        at org.apache.struts2.components.If.start(If.java:86)
        at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.header_jsp._jspx_meth_s_if_0(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.header_jsp:252)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.header_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.header_jsp:97)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1013)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:698)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:80)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:73)
        at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:283)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:154)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.bodyWithSidebar_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_0(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.bodyWithSidebar_jsp:121)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.bodyWithSidebar_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.bodyWithSidebar_jsp:58)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:192)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1013)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:698)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:80)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:73)
        at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:280)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:154)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.main_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_0(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.main_jsp:473)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.main_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.layouts.main_jsp:157)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
        at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
        at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:536)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:915)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I read in the Spring Security FAQ that the Controller/Action is not the best place to secure methods, but the described failure in the FAQ is that the @Secured annotation will not work, i.e. method will not be secured.

In my case, I get a null valuestack even before reaching that method; execute() is not secured, only editUser() and that wasn't even called yet.

I hope someone has the same experience and found a solution .. thanks.

**Update:**
I wonder if this will help: [Spring Security - how I can enable Method Security annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229600/spring-security-how-i-can-enable-method-security-annotations)

My Action classes currently extend a BaseAction class where I put common functionality though ..

Comment: So you're saying that with ROLE_ADMIN it worked fine and now (with TEST_ADMIN) it isn't?

Comment: Have you tried removing the annotation or the security filter in order to verify that the problem really is from the Spring Security filter and not something else?  Also, for clarification, it appears that the `currentPage` variable is `null`, not the `ValueStack` itself.  You have posted all of your action class's code, but I'm assuming that you do in fact have a `getCurrentPage()` method?

Comment: It wouldn't really be honest of Spring Security to fail with a NullPointerException if it couldn't find a getter method for currentPage. It'd better fail with PropertyNotFound or something. But I also don't see why you concluded that the entire ValueStack is null.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the Setter method for currentPage, to see if it is being called at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wonder, this problem occurs if you use the default configuration of Spring Security, where it expects **`ROLE_`** prefixed names.

See this question:
[How do I use custom roles/authorities in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986892/how-do-i-use-custom-roles-authorities-in-spring-security)

> You are using the default configuration witch expects that roles starts with the "ROLE_" prefix. You will have to add a custom security configuration and set rolePrefix to ""

The example configuration from: [Spring Security Role Prefix and Custom User Details Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951832/spring-security-role-prefix-and-custom-user-details-service?rq=1)

```
<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

Related questions:

- [Spring Security ROLE_ prefix no longer needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314690/spring-security-role-prefix-no-longer-needed?rq=1)
- [Acegi Security: How do i add another GrantedAuthority to Authentication to anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283870/acegi-security-how-do-i-add-another-grantedauthority-to-authentication-to-anony)

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace indicates a problem in the 'header.jsp' file, where there is a problem with the  tag. I suspect you simply have a nullpointer problem with the expression in the  tag. Can you share the JSP snippet of header.jsp ?

Answer (score 1):

this won't directly answer your question, but you would have a much easier time of integration if you utilize Spring 3 MVC Controllers with annotations and use a Spring Security version that matches. This would give you the added benefit of being able to develop it faster, ditch the XML configuration for your controllers and it would only take a few minutes to switch. Depending on how far into your implementation you are, this may be an option. Typically Spring annotations only work when they are within a Spring managed beans or you weave dependencies into non Spring classes at compile or runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I already did work with a project like this. I used Struts 2, Spring 3.0.0 and Spring Security.

I think you could try to annotate the struts actions with @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller ... this is the current way to Spring manage your Struts Action. I think it will fix the spring security issue you was related.

I remember another particularity about this architecture. In web.xml you must set the spring listeners and filters before the Struts 2 filters. I found my old project and my web.xml was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="starter" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Onleague.com</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Struts 2 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Sitemesh -->    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Welcome file lists -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Good luck!